# Limit umbraco website size

Tags: umbraco

**My Question is:**

Is it possible to limit the maximum size of Umbraco website? -say 1GB for example-

---

**In other words:**

The problem here on [media folder]

- Is its size limited?

  - if Yes, How to modify the limit?
  - if No , Is it possible to limit it?

Comment: @Zac: not easily in Umbraco or in general?

Comment: In Umbraco. CMS users with access to the media section can upload any number of items. Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to find a way to limit the size of the whole website, let that user upload any number of files but with a constraint on "total files size"

Comment: Are you talking about CMS users, or umbraco members uploading media?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, not really. The more involved answer is below.

There are quite a few factors which affect the size of a project other than the media. For example the database size, the packages installed, the indexes, temporary files, log files.

If your goal is to control the the size because you want to control your hosting space then I would suggest that you just don't and you look at better hosting. It is *very* bad practice to put constraints on a client because of your bad planning. Look at offloading the media to Azure or Amazon S3 where size is irrelevant and storage is incredibly cheap. You can use storage providers in Umbraco to enable this.

However, let's say there was a legitimate reason for restricting the total file size of the media folder. You could easily use an Umbraco Event to intercept the creation of media items and after checking the file size of the media folder either cancel or allow the media item to be created.

Of course this then poses the issue of how do you let the user know why you have cancelled their media creation? All in all it's not a great idea.